# Why can't my onclick handler find its parent node?

Tags: javascript, html

Why does the onclick handler below trigger an "elem.parentNode is not a function" error?

```
<html>
  <head>
   <script type="text/javascript">
     function getParent(elem) {
       var parent = elem.parentNode();
     }
   </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div style="border: solid black 2px">
      <span onclick="getParent(this)">hello</span>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: That's got to be the fastest 9 responses ever!

Comment: Obviously I posted before I saw Paolo's response come up.  Why 7 other people would post the same answer shortly after... I dunno.

Comment: I didn't get the New answers alert while I was writing my answer

Comment: The SO heartbeat thing that checks for new answers is flaky these days.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your problem is that parentNode is not a function. Try removing the `()`.

Answer (score 3):

parentNode is a property, not a function.

```
var parent = element.parentNode;
```

Answer (score 2):

Because `parentNode` is not a function?  Try `elem.parentNode` without the parenthesis.

Answer (score 2):

it should be

```
 function getParent(elem) {
   var parent = elem.parentNode;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's *not* a function.  It's a property.  Lose the parentheses.

var parent = elem.parentNode;

Answer (score 1):

parentNode is a property not a function. Drop the () and it should work.

Answer (score 1):

parentNode isn't a function, it's a property.